# Invalid Column Name issue

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am working in vb.net and facing an Issue of invalid column name when accessing the data from SQL.
I am using MSSQL as back-end.

I referred many links, googled alot but unable to solve my problem

The code where I am facing problem is :

```
Private Sub txtAccCode_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtAccCode.TextChanged
    Try
           mQry = " from FAMPAR where Account_Code = '" & txtAccCode.Text & "'"
        If Not CheckEof("select *" & mQry, con1) Then
            txtAccName.Text = GetData("select Party_Name " & mQry, con1)
            txtProPart.Text = GetData("select Proprietor" & mQry, con1)
            txtRef.Text = GetData("select Reference_By" & mQry, con1)
            txtAdd1.Text = GetData("select Address_1" & mQry, con1)
            txtAdd2.Text = GetData("select Address_2" & mQry, con1)
            txtCity.Text = GetData("select City" & mQry, con1)
            txtPhno.Text = GetData("select Phone_No" & mQry, con1)
            txtEmail.Text = GetData("select Email" & mQry, con1)
            txtDrugLic.Text = GetData("select Drug_License" & mQry, con1)
            txtGst.Text = GetData("select GST_No" & mQry, con1)
            txtCst.Text = GetData("select CST_No" & mQry, con1)
            txtCustBank.Text = GetData("select Customer_Bank" & mQry, con1)
            txtAreaCode.Text = GetData("select Area_Code" & mQry, con1)
            txtCustGrpCode.Text = GetData("select Cust_GrpCode" & mQry, con1)
            txtDisc.Text = GetData("select Disc_Perc" & mQry, con1)
            txtOpeningBal.Text = GetData("select Open_Bal" & mQry, con1)
            txtCurrBal.Text = GetData("select Curr_Bal" & mQry, con1)
            txtCcd.Text = GetData("select CC_DD" & mQry, con1)
            txtStopDays.Text = GetData("select Stop_Days" & mQry, con1)
            txtBillOutstdg.Text = GetData("select Fix_Days" & mQry, con1)
            txtRemarks.Text = GetData("select Description" & mQry, con1)
            cmbRetTax.Text = GetData("select Retail_Taxable" & mQry, con1)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The GetData function I used in above code is

```
Function GetData(qry As String, Xcn As SqlConnection)
    Try
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(qry, Xcn)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        GetData = IIf(Trim(dt.Rows(0).Item(0)) <> "", Trim(dt.Rows(0).Item(0)), "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
```

Now the problem is it works correct till textAreaCode.text but after than from textCustGrpCode.text error starts saying "invalid Column name (name of column)". The error screen-shot is shown in the link below..

[Error Image-Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq5z6.png)

The other thing is when I twist txtAreaCode.text line position with txtCustGrpCode.text line or any other below it, textAreaCode.text gives the error as "Invalid Column Name(column Name)" and the other line works properly.

Plz tell me where I did mistake...
Any help will be accepted..!

Comment: Check your table schema. What are the column names?

Comment: That code is very inefficient.  You query the database to get all columns in a row and then you just throw that data away and proceed to query the database once for each column.  That is CRAZY!  Fix that code to be sane before worrying about anything else.  Execute one query to get all columns, either into a `DataTable` or, even better, via a data reader and then get each field from that.

Comment: column names are perfect. Watch my last paragraph I written about twisting position.. @alldayremix

Comment: okie..! :/ @jmcilhinney

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict and use SQL Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use data adapter and data table to it would be a lot easy to put selected column data to the text box.

```
        strQuery = " SELECT * FROM DIVISION ORDER BY DIVISIONCODE"

        Dim DataAdapeter As New SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, myConnection)

        Dim dsDivision As New DataSet
        myConnection.Open()
        DataAdapeter.Fill(dsDivision)

        DtDivision = dsDivision.Tables("DIVISION")

        myConnection.Close()


            DrDivision = DtDivision.Rows(i)
            textbox1.text = DrDivision("DIVISION").ToString                     
            textbox2.text = DrDivision("DIVISIONCODE").ToString
```

this code might help you understand how to use table adapter and data table.

Answer (score 0):

Add **Description field [Description]** as this is **keywoard**. check other field if any